# Crystal Report - Suppress blob field

Tags: crystal-reports

How to suppress blob field...when I using this formula,

it show "**A blob field cannot use a Formula**"

```
if({report.Image})='' then true;
```

Comment: try using `ISNULL` instead

Comment: Thanks a Lot dude..It's Work.....

Answer (score 0):

Right click the image field (report.Image) and choose Format Graphic and make sure the Format Editor is on the Common Tab. Then it should be possible to use the formula.